# Match two spaces with incremental search

Tags: search, whitespace

When searching using:

```
C-s SPC SPC
```

Also matches single spaces. I want to match exactly two space.

Comment: The thing is that it violates the principle of least surprise IMHO. In the past I always preferred Emacs, because it did what I wanted, not what Emacs wanted ("beware of artificial intelligence").

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `M-s SPC` during Isearch to toggle matching whitespace literally. When matching literally, each `SPC` char you type is matched individually.  (This used to be the default Emacs behavior, BTW.)

To configure this as the default behavior customize option `search-whitespace-regexp` to `nil`. (`M-x customize-option search-whitespace-regexp`.)

See the GNU Emacs manual, node [`Special Isearch`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html#Special-Isearch).

`C-h v search-whitespace-regexp` tells us this (showing the default value):

> **`search-whitespace-regexp`** is a variable defined in `isearch.el`.
>
> Its value is `"\\s-+"`
>
> Documentation:
>
> If non-`nil`, regular expression to match a sequence of whitespace chars.
>
> When you enter a space or spaces in the incremental search, it
> will match any sequence matched by this regexp.  As an exception,
> spaces are treated normally in regexp incremental search if they
> occur in a regexp construct like `[...]` or `*`, `+` or `?`.
>
> If the value is a string, it applies to both ordinary and
> regexp incremental search.  If the value is `nil`, or
> `isearch-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for ordinary incremental search, or
> `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for regexp incremental search,
> then each space you type matches literally, against one space.
>
> You might want to use something like `"[ \t\r\n]+"` instead.
> In the Customization buffer, that is `[` followed by a space,
> a tab, a carriage return (control-M), a newline, and `]+`.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 24.3 of Emacs.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Might be good to actually put the .emacs line `(set-variable 'search-whitespace-regexp nil)` in there.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gray: `set-variable` doesn't save the new value persistently, so that won't change the default behavior. I think `M-x customize-option` is what is called for here.

Comment: Oh I was talking about it in the dot emacs file.  Didn't know about customize option.  Thanks for editing.

Comment: @Drew The answer could benefit if you'd explain not just how to fix it, but also explain what is happening by default. Also I think the behavior was different in the past (being an old-time Emacs user). The "feature" seems to be new since Emacs 25.1 (`search-default-mode`, `isearch-regexp-function`)

Comment: @U.Windl: Done. (It's apparently Emacs 24.3, BTW.)

Answer (score 4):

Using regexp incremental search solves the problem, if you escape the space characters:

```
C-M-s \SPC\SPC
```

You can also use search and replace without the backslashes, if that's what you're after:

```
M-% SPC SPC
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem today when building a keyboard macro. This answer solved the problem for me, though I had to use the key combination `ESC C-s` instead. See also https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags/issues/64

Comment: Either I don't understand the meaning of `\SPC`, or it doesn't work for me (Emacs 24.3.1):

Comment: Use a backslash character followed by a space character.

Answer (score 3):

Using regexp search helps, but you can also make sure of literal spaces for the search using <kbd>C-q SPC</kbd> to quote a space into the search.

To riff off of @Rovanion's answer then, using `isearch-forward-regexp`:

<kbd>C-M-s</kbd> <kbd>C-q SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-q SPC</kbd>

That will search for two consecutive spaces. Interestingly, `isearch-forward-regexp` requires discrete matches. Searching `aaa` for `aa` will only match once and not again at the second character.

Comment: Regarding your last note, imagine searching for "zero or more whitespace followed by a thing" and, given N characters of leading whitespace, needing to step through all N+1 individual matches.  I can see that being a reasonable *option* to provide, but it would be a terrible default.

Comment: Actually whether using a plain space character (SPC) or qoting it in incremental search does *not* make a difference (in Emacs 24.3.1); it only works for `C-M-s`, but not for `C-s`. Maybe improve the answer to explain in greater detail.