# searching for explicit spaces, without reinterpretation

Tags: regular-expressions, search, isearch, whitespace

Often I'll search (an ordinary i-search) for a sequence of two spaces, or three, or four.

But on one machine I'm using, emacs by default appears to be in some mode where searches for spaces are special.  For example, a search for two spaces will "find" a tab — I guess because a tab "looks like" two (or more) spaces.

Does anyone know what this mode might be, or how to turn it off?  (Whatever the mode is, it's active even in Fundamental mode.)

I'm observing this with emacs 24.3.1.  I do not observe it with 22.1.1 or 26.1.  But I suspect it's a configuration thing, not a version-specific thing.

Comment: Duplicate: [Match two spaces with incremental search](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2819/match-two-spaces-with-incremental-search) (also answered by Drew).  Dunno why I couldn't find that first.

Comment: Thanks for finding the dup. I too didn't find it when searching. I've voted to close this question now. And I added tag `isearch` to the dup question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match two spaces with incremental search](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2819/match-two-spaces-with-incremental-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SPC` char normally matches all whitespace defined by option
`search-whitespace-regexp`.  You can customize this option, so you get the matching you want by default.  `C-h v search-whitespace-regexp` tells us, in addition to more info about the option:

> If the value is `nil`, or [if]
> `isearch-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for ordinary incremental search, or
> `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace` is `nil` for regexp incremental search, then **each space you type matches literally, against one space**.

Use key `M-s SPC` during Isearch to toggle this behavior.  `C-h k M-s SPC` says:

> **`isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function
> in `isearch.el`.
> ?
> `(isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace)`
>
> Toggle lax-whitespace searching on or off.
>
> In ordinary search, toggles the value of the variable
> `isearch-lax-whitespace`.  In regexp search, toggles the
> value of the variable `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace`.

You can of course set the default values of those individual variables (they're not user options, however), to define the default behavior you prefer. But a mode etc. can change their values, overriding the values you set. (And a mode can change the value of `search-whitespace-regexp`, though modes are generally not supposed to override user options.)

At least you can toggle the behavior at any time.

If you are seeing this *only for Emacs version 24.3.1*, do you also see the problem if you start that Emacs version using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

---

**Not-so-well-known tip:**

When regexp isearching, you can use **`C-q SPC`** to search for a single space char at a time. No need to fiddle with any lax/strict whitespace matching.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks very much.  Oddly, `emacs -Q` didn't help.

Comment: But the relevant setq's are in my .emacs now, and all is right in the world again (with respect to whitespace searches, anyway :-) ).